# PL-SQL: getting column data types out of query results

Tags: oracle, plsql

Trying to make a generic PL/SQL procedure to export data in specific XML format, e.g. Excel XML. Let's say the procedure accepts a string with the SELECT query to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

This requires access to data types of each column of the resulting rowset, which -- seeing as the procedure is to be generic -- is only known after the query is run.

I have tried an approach with a temporary table, but for the procedure to compile the table must exist and have its structure known at compile time.

How can I next process the rows and columns of an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE result in a double loop that analyzes the type of each value and emits an appropriate piece of XML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do that with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. You'll have to use the more powerful (and more complex) [DBMS_SQL package](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#i1026120) - I've linked you to the DESCRIBE_COLUMNS procedure, which is especially relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Or query ALL_TAB_COLS to get the column datatype.

Comment: I had the same thought at first, but if the input is the full query, e.g. 'SELECT a, b, c FROM some_table', then you would have to parse out the column names from the query.  Using DBMS_SQL is probably better since you can have Oracle do the parsing for you.